# Java best practice to manage ImageIcons

Tags: java, image, netbeans, imageicon

I built an application in java (netbeans) and I'm using the ImageIcon class to create fancy buttons. Currently I'm storing images in a folder and I'm loading them as soon as I need them for displaying.

There are two problems with this approach: The user can a) delete or b) modify them where I think the latter is the most important one to prohibit.

After spending an afternoon on serializing image and imageicon objects I'm quite frustrated and I wonder if there is a best practice method for this like zipping them and unzipping to memory or working with hashes etc.

Every hint appreciated!

Comment: put them in the jar file with the class files, but remember to acquire them as resources, not as files

Comment: Even with a JAR, a determined user can still mess things up, so there are some limitations on how much effort you can (or should) devote to idiot-proofing things. You might be worrying about nothing.